# How to do redirect the URL of site

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, home-page

How to I redirect the **https://www.example.com/home** to **https://www.example.com**

I have tried redirect through URL Rewrite Management

With below details:
Type : Custom 
Request path : /home 
Target Path : /

but it is not working

Comment: Do you want to move your site from  https://www.example.com/home  to https://www.example.com?

Comment: i want to just redirect the url from example.com/home to example.com

Comment: is this a page or what?

Comment: it just default home page

Comment: please check my answer

Comment: Well to change the home-page, you can do with core-config-data but thats same to change the site URL.  First of this check @NikunjVadariya answer if you need that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type: Custom

Store: Select the appropriate store.

ID Path: home

Request Path: home

Target Path: **../**

Redirect: Permanent (301)

Description: Redirects /home to /

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Type**: Custom
**Store:** Select the appropriate store.
**ID Path**: home
**Request Path**: /home
**Target Path**: ./ (if its not working then try ../)
**Redirect**: Permanent (301)
**Description**: From /home to /

I used same thing and its worked for me. So just tried it.